# Eclipse, how to find how many attributes defined in a class?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I'm using Eclipse, how can I get how many attributes I defined in a class?

For example, in class `User`, I have 5 attributes (5 red squares).

While in some class there are so many attributes, it is hard to count them one by one...

[image]

Comment: Well.. You already know.

Comment: @MarounMaroun This example is a "small" class, while in some "large" class, the attributes are so many, it is hard to count one by one...

Comment: You can select them all, then at the left bottom corner you'll see "X items selected".

Comment: @MarounMaroun Cool, it works! Could you please add your answer so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select them all, then at the left bottom corner you'll see "X items selected", for example:

[image]